# Set Host-header when using Python and urllib2

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I'm using my own resolver and would like to use urllib2 to just connect to the IP (no resolving in urllib2) and I would like set the HTTP Host-header myself. But urllib2 is just ignoring my Host-header:

```
txheaders = { 'User-Agent': UA, "Host: ": nohttp_url }
robots = urllib2.Request("http://" + ip  + "/robots.txt", txdata, txheaders)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have included `": "` in the `"Host"` string.

```
txheaders = { "User-Agent": UA, "Host": nohttp_url }
robots = urllib2.Request("http://" + ip  + "/robots.txt", txdata, txheaders)
```

Comment: Haha, thanks for noticing the typo. Should I/can I remove my question?