# Why does my host header not work?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a man-in-the-middle for a webserver (to add extra services, not for nefarious reasons.

I am trying to pass a `Host` header, since the back-end put's it's address, as taken from the `Host` header, in the reply in lots of unpredictable places.

The original code is hundreds of lines, so I've simplified it to just the salient parts here.

```python
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))

opener.addheaders.append(('Host','fakedomain.net'))

res = opener.open('http://www.google.com/doodles/finder/2014/All%20doodles')

res.read()
```

When I run this code, I expect `Host: fakedomain.net` to be passed to google's server. However, the debug code clearly shows `Host: www.google.com\r\n`. Changing `Host` to `HostX` works fine.

What is the correct way of sending a `Host:` header with an opener?

Note: this is a simplification; in the actual code, I am pointing to my own server, etc. - this is a simplification.

Comment: This is what I see when I run your code snippet: http://pastebin.com/Tr8p2yTR

Comment: That is exactly what I see. On the first line where it says `Host: www.google.com\r\n` I expected to see `Host: fakedomain.net\r\n`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Host-header when using Python and urllib2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520966/set-host-header-when-using-python-and-urllib2)

Comment: I found that in my searches before writing this question. I want to do the same thing that page does, but using `urllib2.build_opener(...).open(...)` . In case you're wondering why, since this is an http proxy, I have an opener that doesn't follow redirect, but returns it instead. I pass the redirect back to the browser, so the browser knows the URL has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Satoru who got me on the right track, and was almost what I was looking for, and certainly led me on to the right track.

The correct answer is:

```
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))

req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com/doodles/finder/2014/All%20doodles',None,{"Host":"fakedomain.net"})

res = opener.open(req)

res.read()
```

Sorry Satoru, I don't want to select your answer as correct, in case someone else finds my question, but I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `urllib2.Request`,

```
import urllib2

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com/doodles/finder/2014/All%20doodles')
req.add_unredirected_header('Host', 'fakedomain.net')
res = opener.open(req)
res.read()
```